# this.state.category.map is not a function ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, function, frontend

i have many categories on a component and i want to display one specific category on another component using his id .
im using axios and im getting the data im looking for as the image shows

[image]

but the problem is when i want to use the map to display the data i get the following error : this.state.category.map is not a function

there is my code :

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class SingleCategory extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            category:[]
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/show/'+this.props.match.params.id)
        .then(response=>{
            this.setState({category:response.data});
            console.log(this.state.category)
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="w-2/3 bg-red-100 h-60 m-auto mt-10">
                    {
                        this.state.category.map(cat=> {
                            return(
                                <div>{cat.id}</div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default SingleCategory;
```

Comment: Please add result of `console.log(response.data)`

Comment: Also, I don't think `console.log(this.state.category)` will have the right timing, it has to wait for React to tick the state change.

Comment: Its the same as console.log(this.state.category) , it works just fine , but when i add the map function it doesn't show anymore.

Comment: The logged data show a plain object, and not an array.

Comment: i also changed the  this.state={
            category:{}
        }   , but it dosent work

Comment: @Chaker.asm yes but plain objects do not have a `.map` method. So instead of `this.state.category.map` you should probably just directly use `<div>{this.state.category.id}</div>`

Comment: @Chaker.asm Add response of `console.log(response.data)` instead of `console.log(this.state.category)`along with the question.

Comment: @Danial here is the result of the console.log : {id: 1, name: "test1", active: 1, created_at: "2021-08-18", updated_at: "2021-08-18"}
active: 1
created_at: "2021-08-18"
id: 1
name: "test1"
updated_at: "2021-08-18"
__proto__: Object

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Yeah thats works fine , Thank you mate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that plain objects do not have a .map method.
Instead of using this.state.category.map . just directly use

```
<div>{this.state.category.id}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, result of API is an object, not an **`array`**. So `map` can't call on Objects.

Answer (score 1):

As per the resp.data object example, looks like you are getting object not list from api. Map works only with the list.